# Under the hood, what is Quickly made of?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, programming

under the hood, What is [Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly) made of?

It's a wrapper to python? It's a compiled language? It's portable? What about the architecture and the design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quickly** is a group of programs and scripts (such as Gedit, Glade or quickly itself) which allows you to easily create a Python/GTK-based Ubuntu program. It creates your app importing a template, then you can modify the UI and the scripts, and finally, it allows you to share your app creating Debian packages or uploading to a Launchpad PPA.

As is based in Python (yep, it's a wrapper!), Quickly is architecture-independent. You can edit and run your Quickly apps on an i386, x86_64 or ARM-based computer with no trouble.

To install it, [just click here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/quickly).

It has no GUI interface, so you have to use the terminal. Here you have some simple commands:

- `quickly create ubuntu-application <project_name>` creates the project. `cd <project_name>` after finished.
- `quickly edit` opens the script files using Gedit. You can edit the app here.
- `quickly design` shows the GUI files using Glade, allowing you to design the menus.
- `quickly run` executes your app. Use this for testing.
- `quickly save` saves your current progress using Bazaar. Set up your Bazaar e-mail before doing this!
- `quickly package` builds a .deb package from your source code.
- `quickly release` uploads your app to your own Launchpad PPA.

I think that a tutorial is better than a small reference guide... so, after installing Quickly, run `quickly tutorial` to get started.

Answer (score 3):

As some examination of `apt-get source quickly` will tell you, Quickly can best be described as a wrapper written in Python.

- `setup.py:31:    print >> sys.stderr, 'To build quickly you need https://launchpad.net/python-distutils-extra'`
- `quickly` executable line 1: `#!/usr/bin/python`
- `~/src/quickly-12.04$ ls  quickly` returns:

  ```
  api.py              bzrbinding.py  configurationhandler.py  init.py         quicklyconfig.py  test      version.py
  builtincommands.py  commands.py    coreupgrade.py           launchpadaccess.py  templatetools.py  tools.py
  ```